# How do I color image on hover?

Tags: html, css, web, hover

beginner and I'm trying to change color of RSS icon background into orange
I made separate icon with orange background but I don't know how to do it
Here's my code 
HTML: http://pastebin.com/bPZf8DmA
CSS: http://pastebin.com/kwyAnygJ
Many thanks!

Comment: Will you provide a link to a live example? Are you trying to to change the background of a transparent image?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/2SqnS

Comment: Try adding the relevant code to your question — many people will not go to a third-party site to look at it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to change the background of a transparent image (I don't have access to your images so I cannot be sure), you can just add `background-color` to the `:hover` state, like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/we3d9h8o/

```css
img:hover {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://clbin.com/VMHNmx.png" />
```

EDIT:

Now that you provided the example, this should work for you (swapping `background-image` with css):

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/L1nkh00e/

```css
.rss__icon {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-image: url(https://clbin.com/LSluSU.png);
}
.rss__icon:hover {
  background-image: url(https://clbin.com/5B1Mhb.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="rss__icon"></div>
```

Although, you would be even better off reading up on CSS sprites: https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: I apologize for bad wording, I'm trying to to do this  http://imgur.com/a/2SqnS

Comment: Thank you so much and thank you for the CSS sprites link.

Comment: @JhonDhoe, if this answer works, please accept it.